# What is the use of Substitution is not failure

Tags: c++, sfinae

I have a class, Jav::String that I make use of templates.

```
 class String
 {
  String();
  String(std::size_t);

  template <class ITER_WRAP>
  String(const ITER_WRAP &iterator_begin_end);
 }
```

I expect when I call string with a signed integer , as what MAX_PATH is, it would call the std::size_t aka unsigned int overload; since I expect that Substitution is not failure! Basically, an int does not have begin, end elements so substitution should fail and that function should not be a part of the candidate functions.

However, to my terror, I get a compile error, const int has no begin or end member.

When is Substitution a failure and when is it not. Does it only work for types.

Comment: If you are interested in SFINAE from the ground up, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Am2is2QCvxY might be a good presentation to watch.

Answer (score 1):

Substitution Failure is Not An Error (SFINAE) is only concerned with substitution of template arguments during overload resolution. All it basically means is that if substitution of deduced template arguments during the process of figuring out which function to call leads to an invalid type or expression being produced somewhere, then that will not result in a compilation failure, but will simply lead to the respective function not being considered a potential candidate for the function call anymore. Only stuff that appears in the declaration of a function template (or partial class or variable template specialization) can be subject to SFINAE. The potential instantiation of the definition of a function template happens after it has been determined which function to call exactly. If substitution of a template argument gives rise to an invalid construct during instantiation of the definition of a function template, such a substitution failure is very much going to be an error.

In your particular case, given the two options

```
String(std::size_t);

template <class ITER_WRAP>
String(const ITER_WRAP &iterator_begin_end);
```

a call of the `String` constructor with an argument of type `int` will pick the template specialization `String<int>` because calling `String(std::size_t)` requires an integral promotion which has a worse conversion rank than the exact match that `String<int>` gives you…

Comment: Thanks. I edited my String ctor with an extra template called class X = decltype(X::begin). problem is users can overwrite default parameters.